# Linux live CD/DVD that includes UnionFS (but not Knoppix)

Tags: linux, usb, optical-media, linux-distribution

Tried to use the latest Knoppix and running into lots of issues.  It can't seem to decide whether it's `systemd` or SysV `init` based, and simple things like restarting the network after a config change seem to be a major challenge.

So I'm looking for an alternative that comes pre-built with UnionFS, allowing a R/W overlay when booting from a USB thumb drive.

Answer (score 1):

Both Mint and Ubuntu can do persistence. Or even be installed directly to USB w/ boot loader written to USB.

I prefer Mint - Ubuntu made me upset with some changes a few versions ago...  Here's how to do persistence on Mint - https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=42&t=229086